# Why does jQuery break this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i use a jQuery id selector to select an element, it does not function the same as if i use plain JS. Why does the does the display block, or the src not change when using jQuery, but works with plain JS?

See JS line 2 has working code
comment that out and uncomment line 3 and select the element with the jQuery and it stops working.

### HTML

```
<img id="myImg" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// var modal = $("#myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

http://codepen.io/Zlerp/pen/xEqEAQ?editors=1010

Comment: Please don't paste your CSS when it's not related.

Comment: jQuery elements and DOM elements are different things.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple.  When jQuery selects an element, it isn't the ELEMENT per se it's selecting, it's a jQuery object containing that element.  If you do $("selector")[0], that will return the correct object.  Or you can set style using the css function, e.g. $("selector").css("property","value").

Comment: I havent seen this before in any jQuery tutorials. Do you know where I can find more information on selectors like these?

Comment: To clarify, I think you may still be confused, having glanced at the edits on your codepen.  There are two types of objects involved here, the builtin HTML element, which seems to be the one you're used to, and the jQuery element.  What you seem to want to do is to use a jQuery selector and get an HTML element, but there are ways to do this the other way.  You could, for instance, select an element using the builtin javascript and apply styles using jQuery (e.g. `$(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).css("background","red")`) ...and I'm out of characters.  One sec.

Comment: You're doing it the other way around, namely taking a jQuery object, which is essentially a package of functions around an HTML element, and trying to use the builtin HTML functions on it.  You could do all your code without jQuery at all (and you might have an easier time).  In fact you use document.GetElementById successfully in your code.  Why not just select your image that way too?  Or you could learn the jQuery functions.  They tend to be worthwhile.

Comment: Documentation for jQuery functions can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/ and documentation for builtin functions can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#Methods